# Haskell: Runtime Data Type Iteration?

Tags: haskell, types, generic-programming

A friend and I have been working on a system for automatically importing C functions into GNU Guile, but need to use Haskell's C parser because no other parser seems sufficient or as accessible (let me know if we're wrong about that).

The trouble is coming up when we try to produce Scheme data from the parsed AST. We need to produce text that can be directly imported by scheme (S-Expressions, not M-Expressions), so below is an example...

```
toscm $ Just (SomeType (AnotherType "test" 5) (YetAnother "hello!"))
=> "(Just (SomeType (AnotherType \"test\" 5) (YetAnother \"hello!\")))"
```

The output of Haskell's C parser has type (Either ParseError CTranslUnit). CTranslUnit is a specialization (CTranslationUnit NodeInfo). The CTranslationUnit's contents have ever more contents going deeper than is really any fun at all.

Before realizing that, I tried the following...

```
class Schemable a where
  toscm :: a -> String

{- and then an (omitted) ridiculously (1000+ lines) long chain
of horrible instance declarations for every single type
that can be part of the C AST -}
```

I figured there really must be a better way to do this, but I haven't been able to find one I understand.  [`GHC.Generics`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html) seems like it might have a solution, but the semantics of some of its internal types baffles me.

What should I do??

---

Update: I've been looking into Scrap Your Boilerplate, and while it definitely looks good for finding substructures, it doesn't provide a way for me to generically convert data to strings. The ideal would be if the data with the constructor Maybe (CoolType "awesome" (Something "funny")) could be processed with a function that would give me access to the names of the constructors, and allow me to recurse on the values of the arguments to that constructor. e.g...

```
data Constructorized = Constructed String [Constructorized]
                     | RawValue <anything>

constructorize :: <anything> -> Constructorized
constructorize a = <???>

toscm :: Constructorized -> String
toscm (Constructed c v) = "(" ++ c ++ " " ++ (intercalate " " (map toscm v)) ++ ")"
toscm (RawValue v) = show v
```

---

I guess the train of thought I'm on is: Show seems to be able to recurse into every single type that derives it, no problem. How are the functions for that generated? Shouldn't we be able to make our own Show that generates similar functions, with a slightly different output?

Comment: Perhaps scrap-your-boilerplate and `deriving Data` can help. I can't see for sure, though. (Also you mention GADTs in the title but not in the question (?))

Comment: I assumed that the "data" expression declares a GADT? If that's the case, then my need is effectively to traverse all components of a GADT recursively into all sub-GADTs. I'll take a look at SYB

Comment: @MilesRufat-Latre: What you have are simply algebraic data types, or ADTs (no G). [A GADT is a *generalized* algebraic data type](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#gadt), which can have constructors with more interesting types; I don't have a good resource for explaining them at hand, though. (Also, I would be remiss if I didn't mention that ADT can also stand for the unrelated notion of an abstract data type, so there are [certain people](http://stackoverflow.com/users/828361/pigworker) who advocate for abolishing the acronym.)

Comment: Read the original Scrap Your Boilerplate paper. Before I read that I was baffled about how to use it, but it's actually quite simple for practical cases. And my guess is that it will fit your problem well.

Comment: Thanks! Haven't had a chance to read it quite yet, but will let you know!

Comment: I'm curious -- have you looked at `gshow`? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb-0.6/docs/src/Data-Generics-Text.html#gshow

It looks like it essentially does what you're asking for...